# Keystroke command to Show All Bookmarks in Safari not working

Tags: applescript, keystroke

I am trying a simple Keystroke command to Show All Bookmarks in Safari 5.0.2 but it is not working -

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "B" using {option down, command down}
end tell
end
```

Can anyone suggest me where I may be wrong?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a little 'b':

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "b" using {option down, command down}
end tell
```

The big B translates to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.